# Why is my question closed?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, off-topic, reopen-closed

My question was recently closed as off-topic, and received downvotes. It's a question related to caching errors in Magento. There's no code included in the question, but after reviewing the FAQ

> > Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers …
> >
> > a specific programming problem
> >     a software algorithm
> >     **software tools commonly used by programmers**

I feel as though the question is legitimate, as many programmers use this tool! So why is it closed and downvoted?

Original question: [Magento slow-down overnight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13686308/magento-slow-down-overnight)

Comment: The question has been answered, so what reason do you have for it to need to be re-opened?  It's not like it's been deleted, or is likely to be deleted.

Comment: Mainly curiosity...and justice!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a bit of an edge case maybe, and would be a cool question to have around now that you even provided the answer (which is good info,  +1!)

However, overall it really is a Magento administration question rather than a programming one, and indeed off topic. Microsoft Word and OpenOffice also are "software tools commonly used by programmers", but that doesn't mean you can ask questions about them on SO.

If one day there will be a [dedicated Magento site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/25439/magento), it will surely be on topic there. I'd say leave it be for now, and flag for migration once that site starts.

Comment: Thank you Pekka! The fact that it has to do with caching and compiling, it feels a bit more programm-ey than a MS Word question, but I can see how it's borderline. 

I definitely hope SO starts a Magento community...the current Magento support forums are seriously lacking